# C: How do I convert a string to int which will be in long int format

Tags: c, string, integer, atoi

I want to convert a string `"12341234123412341234"` to int, but when I use atoi it returns `-1`

```
char n[100] = "12341234123412341234";
printf("%d",atoi(n));
```

returns `-1`

if i use `%ld` or `%lld` it returns a junk value

```
char n[100] = "12341234123412341234";
printf("%lld",atoi(n)); //even if i use %ld it returns the same value
```

returns `4294967295`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`atoi` returns an `int`. The largest value that can have on a typical 32 or 64 bit architecture (with 32 bit `int`) is `2147483647`. So whatever `atoi` would return in your case depends on the implementation, but we can be fairly sure that it wont be `12341234123412341234`

Trying to tell `printf` that the parameter passed to it is a `long` or a `long long` using `"%ld"` or `"%lld"` cannot work either. It doesn't change the fact that `atoi` returns an `int`, and that is what get passed to `printf`. So in addition to that the return value from `atoi` is not what you want, you are lying about the datatype passed to `printf`. Nothing good comes out of lying to your computer. Besides `long` and `long long` can typically not hold the value `12341234123412341234` either.

An integer type of `uint64_t` can hold values from `0` to `18446744073709551615` which should work in your case. Typically `uint64_t` is the same as `unsigned long long`, and you can use `strtoull` to parse that:

```
const char *n = "12341234123412341234";
char *end;
unsigned long long v = strtoull(n, &end, 10);
printf ("%llu\n", v);
```

Naturally, if the string `n` comes from untrusted sources, a robust program should inspect the pointer `end` for parse errors.

See `man strtoull` for more info.

You should also check out `INT_MAX` and `ULLONG_MAX` (and other `*_MAX`) for your architecture.

Answer (score 3):

The function you want is `strtol`:

```
char n[100] = "12341234123412341234";
printf("%llu", strtoull(n, NULL, 10));
```

Comment: it returns `9223372036854775807`, I want it to return `12341234123412341234` in int.

Comment: @CLOUD1015 Ah, the value is too big for a `long`, but not an `unsigned long long`, so use `strtoull`.